# Subdomains for different applications on Windows Server 2008 R2 with Apache and IIS 7 installed

Tags: apache-2.2, networking, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2, subdomain

I have a home server, on which I have installed Apache, and several other applications that have a Web GUI (JDownloader, Free Download Manager).

In order to access each of these apps (whether be it from the local network or the Internet), I have to enter a different port, e.g.,

```
http://server:8085 or http://xxxx.dyndns.org:8085 for Apache  
http://server:90   or http://xxxx.dyndns.org:90   for FDM  
http://server:8081 or http://xxxx.dyndns.org:8081 for JDownloader
```

I would like to be able to access them using sub-domains, e.g,

```
http://apache.server      or http://apache.xxxx.dyndns.org      for Apache,
http://fdm.server         or http://fdm.xxxx.dyndns.org         for FDM,
http://jdownloader.server or http://jdownloader.xxxx.dyndns.org for JDownloader
```

First of all, would it be possible like I want it, i.e., both from LAN and Internet, and if yes, how? Even if it's possible only for Internet, I would like to know how to do it, if there's a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible, yes, but I don't know if you'll find a free solution on Windows.  You'd want to install a reverse proxy server which would listen on port 80 for incoming connections.  It would look for requests to the appropriate hostname and then forward those connections internally to the appropriate local IP/port combination (for example, apache.xxxx.dyndns.org -> localhost:8085).

Comment: Ah, thank you very much Justin, I'll try investigating that solution.

Comment: @Yusuf: nginx can act as a reverse proxy, and runs on Windows. As far as I know stackoverflow/serverfault/etc. uses it as part of their stack... http://nginx.org/

Comment: Thanks Matt, I'll try that as soon as I have some time; I hope there's nothing like conflicts with IIS7 or Apache, since it is also an HTTP server?